# What is the difference between Index Scan, Table Scan, and an Index Seek?

Tags: sql-server

Can any one briefly explain what's the difference between these 3 Index Scan, Table Scan, and an Index Seek?

Answer (score 3):

Index Scan

> Index Scan scans each and every record in the index. `Table Scan` is where the table is
>       processed row by row from beginning to end. If the index is a clustered index then an 
>       index scan is really a table scan. Since a scan touches every row in the table whether or 
>       not it qualifies, the cost is proportional to the total number of rows in the table. 
>       Hence, a scan is an efficient strategy if the table is small.

Index Seek

> Since a seek only touches rows that qualify and pages that contain these qualifying 
>        rows, the cost is proportional to the number of qualifying rows and pages rather than to 
>        the total number of rows in the table.